# How to import a document class file into another flash file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I have 2 .fla files and one of them is associated with a class file called DocumentMain, it is a game. and what I want is when I click "stat" on the first .fla file  it takes me to the game swf file.

I did the myLoad function and it look like this :

```
btnstart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gamecontent);
function gamecontent(myevent:MouseEvent):void
{
   var myLoader:Loader = new Loader ();
   var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("game.swf");
   myLoader.load(myURL);
   addChild(myLoader);
}
```

but I get an Error which is :

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at DocumentMain()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `addChild(myLoader);` add :

```
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
```

then create this function:

```
function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event):void{
    addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
```

or add this inisde `DocumentMain()` class:

```
public function DocumentMain():void{
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event):void{...
```

Answer (score -1):

Add following code to your `gameContent` function:

```
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
```

The onComplete handler looks like this:

```
function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
{
    addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
```

Could you try this? :)
Although still possible that you are getting errors ... If so: compile the external `SWF` and run this `SWF`, does is run like it should? Or dus the external `SWF` create errors?

If you're still getting the errors, please post the code you're using in the external `SWF`.